# Are there any ready-made Java libraries for transferring images through TCP?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, adb

I'm trying to make an Android app (for private use) that basically allows me to use the device display as sort of second display for Windows. I figured out how to get the image I have to send to the device. I figured out how to connect the two through USB (with adb). Now, I can't figure out how to actually send the image data through my TCP socket. Are there any ready-made libraries for this, or is there anyone who already did this and can help me?

Comment: read the jpg in as binary, transfer the bytes

Comment: Preferably with some kind of message framing; ie: writing 4 bytes that represent the number of bytes to be transferred.

Comment: Ok, but how would I get the JPG file from a BufferedImage object?

Comment: don't use a bufferedimage object, read it in as a resource.  You need the raw binary data from the file.  @cHao is correct as well, you want to create some kind of message structure so that you can ensure data integrity.  If you want a premade library just look for libraries designed to handle file transfer, not specifically image transfer.

Answer (score 0):

If your only need is to display images on your device, I would do this:

```
$ adb push img.png /mnt/sdcard/img.png
$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -t image/png -d file:///mnt/sdcard/img.png
```

Comment: Nope, what I'm trying to do is to stream image content to my app.